# Indexing through the linq expression C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4

In this scenario, I'm tring to changes the address line2, if it exits. Im trying to acess the linq object and change its. Is there any better way to do the below code??

```
public IEnumerable<AddressViewModel> GetAddress (long sid)
{
    var data = UnitOfWork.DbContext.PAddresses.Where(x => x.PId == sid)
        .Select(x => new AddressViewModel
        {
            PId = sid,
            AddressLine1 = x.Address.AddressLine1,
            AddressLine2 = x.Address.AddressLine2,
            Suburb = x.Address.Suburb.Name,
         });
    for (var i=0; i<=1 ;i++ )
    {
        if (data.ElementAt(i).AddressLine2 != null && data.ElementAt(i).AddressLine2.ToLower() == data.ElementAt(i).Suburb.ToLower())
        {
            data.ElementAt(i).AddressLine2 = null;
        }
        if (data.ElementAt(i).AddressLine3 != null && data.ElementAt(i).AddressLine3.ToLower() == data.ElementAt(i).Suburb.ToLower())
        {
            data.ElementAt(i).AddressLine3 = null;
        }
    }

    return data;
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a `for` loop that iterates just once? Why don't you store the value `var element = data.Skip(1).FirstOrDefault();` instead, when you can check if `element == null` and reuse `element` going forward?

Comment: `for (var i=0; i<=1 ;i++ )` what is it??

Comment: @lazyberezovsky  It's the programming equivalent of the phrase "going forward". It means nothing, and the same effect can be achieved by simply omitting it entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could effectively do this as part of your projection. Assuming you can only have 1 address (as that's what it looks like), you could do

```
return UnitOfWork.DbContext.PAddresses.SingleOrDefault(x => x.PId == sid)
       .Select(x => new AddressViewModel
       {
           PId = sid,
           AddressLine1 = x.Address.AddressLine1,
           AddressLine2 = String.Compare(x.Address.AddressLine2, x.Address.Suburb.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == 0 ? null : x.Address.AddressLine2,
           Suburb = x.Address.Suburb.Name,
       });
```

The `null` check is irrelevant, the real issue is you want to set it to `null` if it's the same as `Suburb.Name`.

Answer (score 0):

No need for a loop in your case. You'll always loop round 1 time.

You can directly access the element:

```
if (data.ElementAt(i).AddressLine2 != null && data.ElementAt(i).AddressLine2.ToLower() == data.ElementAt(i).Suburb.ToLower())
                {
                    data.ElementAt(i).AddressLine2 = null;
                }
```

As a side note I'd also check that `data` is not null and contains element, otherwise you may encounter a `ArgumentNullException` or `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` exception.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public IEnumerable<AddressViewModel> GetAddress (long sid)
            {
                PAddresses data = UnitOfWork.DbContext.PAddresses.Where(x => x.PId == sid)
                                     .Select(x => new AddressViewModel
                                         {
                                             PId = sid,
                                             AddressLine1 = x.Address.AddressLine1,
                                             AddressLine2 = x.Address.AddressLine2,
                                             Suburb = x.Address.Suburb.Name,
                                         }).singleordefault();

if(data != null )
{
 data.ElementAt(i).AddressLine2 = null;  data.ElementAt(i).AddressLine3 = null;

}
                return data;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Get address

```
var address = UnitOfWork.DbContext.PAddresses.Where(x => x.PId == sid)
                        .Select(x => new AddressViewModel {
                            PId = sid,
                            AddressLine1 = x.Address.AddressLine1,
                            AddressLine2 = x.Address.AddressLine2,
                            Suburb = x.Address.Suburb.Name,
                         }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Change it (if address is not `null`):

```
if (address.AddressLine2 != null && 
    address.AddressLine2.ToLower() == address.Suburb.ToLower())
    address.AddressLine2 = null;

if (address.AddressLine3 != null &&
    address.AddressLine3.ToLower() == address.Suburb.ToLower())
    address.AddressLine3 = null;

return address;
```

---

But better way is follow [Tell Don't Ask Principle](http://pragprog.com/articles/tell-dont-ask) - instead of asking for address properties and making actions based on their values, tell address to update itself. Add method to `AddressViewModel`:

```
public void RemoveDuplicates() // think about better name
{
     if (IsDuplicateOfSuburb(AddressLine2))
         AddressLine2 = null;

     if (IsDuplicateOfSuburb(AddressLine3))
         AddressLine3 = null;
}

private bool IsDuplicateOfSuburb(string addressLine)
{
    if (addressLine == null)
        return false;

    return (addressLine.ToLower() == Suburb.ToLower();
}
```

And call it on your address object:

```
var address = // get from db context
if (address != null)
    address.RemoveDuplicates();
return address;
```

Much cleaner, yes?

Answer (score 0):

Why not do the check inside the lambda?

```
public IEnumerable<AddressViewModel> GetAddress (long sid)
{
    var data = UnitOfWork.DbContext.PAddresses.Where(x => x.PId == sid)
                         .Select(x => new AddressViewModel
                                      {
                                          PId = sid,
                                          AddressLine1 = x.Address.AddressLine1,
                                          AddressLine2 = x.Address.AddressLine2.ToLower() == x.Address.Suburb.Name.ToLower() ? null : x.Address.AddressLine2,
                                          Suburb = x.Address.Suburb.Name,
                                      });
    return data;
}
```